# Groovy vs Groovyc

Tags: groovy

I am new in Groovy and I do not understand the difference between `groovy` and `groovyc`. So if I have this file,

*hello.groovy*

```
println "Hello World"
```

If I run `groovy hello.groovy` it prints "Hello World"

If I run `groovyc hello.groovy` it generates a `.class` file and if I then run `groovy hello` it prints "Hello World"

Now coming from `ruby`, this confuses me. Is groovy a compiled of interpreted language?

Comment: It can be treated as both, as you've seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy is a compiled language, but it allows you to execute scripts.  Calling `groovy` like you did compiles and runs the script.  Calling `groovyc` only compiles your code.

See: http://www.javalobby.org/articles/groovy-intro1/

Answer (score 2):

Groovy is a language which is derived from Java. `groovyc` is the Groovy compiler which is able to produce JVM bytecode that can be executed as any normal Java compiled program.

In both circumstances the code is compiled, either with groovy and groovyc but in the first case it is dynamically compiled into bytecode and executed while with the standalone compiler just the bytecode is generate (and saved for later use)